# how to align col-md-4 with col-md-12 for any device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How may I fix this, I don't want the right space, I was moving the window to check all of the positions, so I seen this, and I tried to fix it, but I couldn't.

The first box is `col-md-12`, and the other boxes are `col-md-4` (4 not 3) in the same row.

**Code:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>title</h1>
            <form>
                ...
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="pimg">
                <img src="" />
                <div class="description">1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="pimg">
                <img src="" />
                <div class="description">2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="pimg">
                <img src="" />
                <div class="description">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Output:**

[image: Bootstrap]

Comment: You're not using bootstrap's grids properly. Each row should total to 12 columns. Plus, containers should contain rows, not vice versa, unless the nested containers also contain rows.

Comment: intercange row and container class

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong, `.container` comes before `.row` and you have to wrap the `.col-md-4` with `.row`

Added `.col-sm-4` for small devices and `.col-xs-4` for extra small devices.

See [Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Snippet

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>title</h1>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="//lorempixel.com/1200/900" />  
      <form>
        ...
      </form>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <div class="pimg">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="//lorempixel.com/600/300" />
        <div class="description">1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <div class="pimg">
       <img class="img-responsive" src="//lorempixel.com/600/300" />
        <div class="description">2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <div class="pimg">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="//lorempixel.com/600/300" />
        <div class="description">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```